# Quadratic optimization - portfolio maximization problems

Tags: r, quadprog, r-portfolioanalytics

In portfolio analysis, given the expectation, we aim to find the weight of each asset to minimize the variance

here is the code

```
install.packages("quadprog")
library(quadprog)

#Denoting annualized risk as an vector sigma
sigma <- c(0.56, 7.77, 13.48, 16.64)

#Formulazing the correlation matrix proposed by question
m <- diag(0.5, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
m[upper.tri(m)] <- c(-0.07, -0.095, 0.959, -0.095, 0.936, 0.997)
corr <- m + t(m)
sig <- corr * outer(sigma, sigma)

#Defining the mean
mu = matrix(c(1.73, 6.65, 9.11, 10.30), nrow = 4)
m0 = 8


Amat <- t(matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1,
                   c(mu),
                   1, 0, 0, 0,
                   0, 1, 0, 0,
                   0, 0, 1, 0,
                   0, 0, 0, 1), 6, 4, byrow = TRUE))
bvec <- c(1, m0, 0, 0, 0, 0)


qp <- solve.QP(sig, rep(0, nrow(sig)), Amat, bvec, meq = 2)
qp

x = matrix(qp$solution)
x
(t(x) %*% sig %*% x)^0.5
```

I understand the formulation of mu and covariance matrix and know the usage of the `quadprog` plot

However, I don‘t understand why `Amat` and `bvec` are defined in this way, why the are 6 by 4 matrix.

$mu0$ is the expectation we aim to have for the portfolio and it is fixed at value 8%

Attached is the question[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are probably aware, the reason that `Amat` has four columns is that there are four assets that you are allocating over. It has six rows because there are six constraints in your problem:

1. The allocations add up to 1 (100%)
2. Expected return = 8%
3. 'Money market' allocation >= 0
4. 'Capital stable' allocation >= 0
5. 'Balance' allocation >= 0
6. 'Growth' allocation >= 0

Look at the numbers that define each constraint. They are why `bvec` is `[1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. Of these six, the first two are equality constraints, which is why `meq` is set to 2 (the other four are greater than or equal constraints).

#### Edited to add:

The way the constraints work is this: each column of `Amat` defines a constraint, which is then multiplied by the asset allocations, with the result equal to (or greater-than-or-equal-to) some target that is set in `bvec`. For example:

The first column of `Amat` is `[1, 1, 1, 1]`, and the first entry of `bvec` is 1. So the first constraint is:

```
1 * money_market + 1 * capital_stable + 1 * balance + 1 * growth = 1
```

This is a way of saying that the asset allocations add up to 1.

The second constraint says that the expected returns add up to 8:

```
1.73 * money_market + 6.65 * capital_stable + 9.11 * balance + 10.32 * growth = 8
```

Now consider the third constraint, which says that the 'Money market' allocation is greater than or equal to zero. That's because the 3rd column of `Amat` is `[1, 0, 0, 0]` and the third entry of `bvec` is 0. So this constraint looks like:

```
1 * money_market + 0 * capital_stable + 0 * balance + 0 * growth >= 0
```

Simplifying, that's the same as:

```
money_market >= 0
```